# Where to find the AJAX indicator image?

Tags: primefaces

I would like the same loading indicator gif as on the Primefaces Showcase:
http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/basic.xhtml

There is no reference to it in the source. Where is it defined ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With development tools you get the [(re)source](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/javax.faces.resource/main/images/loader.gif.xhtml).

May i suggest using a SVG with real transparency instead. Looks much better! There are several [online generators](http://loading.io/) out there.

> [I am not sure how to use this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38889323/where-to-find-the-ajax-indicator-image/38892761?noredirect=1#comment65148329_38892761)

The indicator image is used with `<p:ajaxStatus />` in combination with `<p:graphicImage />` shown in [PrimeFaces ShowCase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/status.xhtml) and explained in [PrimeFaces Documentation](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/guide/primefaces_user_guide_6_0.pdf#%5B%7B%22num%22%3A198%2C%22gen%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22XYZ%22%7D%2C56.7%2C773.3%2C0%5D).
To show it in the lower right corner of the page like on [the page you referenced](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/basic.xhtml) you have to add custom style like:

```xml
<p:ajaxStatus
    style="position: fixed; bottom: 0px; right: 0px; z-index: 9999999999;"
>
    ...
</p:ajaxStatus>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am not sure how to use this. The problem is not the image itself, but where and how to reference it in the code ?

Comment: @Tim So why did you not ask this directly in your question?

Comment: @Tim Updated answer.

Comment: @irieill: But why does it work in the basic example I posted ? There is no ajaxStatus in the source ?

Comment: @Kukeltje Kidding? Notwithstanding that the PrimeFaces guys will not be happy, if the image is refereced from their servers, reference it just like every image directly via _name_ attribute of `<p:graphicImage />` or even with _src_ attribute of a simple `<img />`. If there is no copywrite issue, you better download and add it to your webapp resources and [reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11988415/what-is-the-jsf-resource-library-for-and-how-should-it-be-used) it from there. But i think that should not be part of the answer as it is basic jsf knowlegde, is it not?

Comment: @Tim I think it works because it is not designed as part of the special page you referenced, but of (nearly) all pages of the ShowCase as a feature of the ShowCase (webapp) itself and not as demonstration.

Comment: @Tim I think with source you mean the code snippet on the [ShowCase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/basic.xhtml)? Because in the (real) [source code](https://github.com/primefaces/showcase/blob/master/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/template.xhtml#L676) of the ShowCase the `<p:ajaxStatus />` is there very well.

Answer (score 0):

Generate and download from: http://www.ajaxload.info/
(ajax-loader.gif)

Copy to (for example): *webapp/resources/images*

Code:

```
            <p:ajaxStatus style="height:16px">
                <f:facet name="start">
                    <h:graphicImage name="images/ajax-loader.gif" />
                </f:facet>
                <f:facet name="complete">
                    <h:outputText value="" />
                </f:facet>
            </p:ajaxStatus>
```